# Clarification of excerpt regarding Souslin Lines

Tags: general-topology, reference-request, set-theory

Here is an excerpt from Mary Ellen Rudin's *Lectures on Set Theoretic Topology* during her discussion about Souslin Lines and Trees,

[image]

What is exactly meant by "Collapse each of these intervals to a point and add the first and last point to the space?" My question is essentially, is there a more descriptive way to describe this set $S'$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find this description quite descriptive enough. Let the set of maximal non-trivial closed intervals that are separable be called $\mathcal{I}$. The family  is pairwise disjoint (if two of them intersected, their union would be a larger  such interval, contradicting maximality. Their interiors are non-empty and disjoint so $\mathcal{I}$ is countable as a Souslin line is ccc. Now take the equivalence relation that has as elements all members of $\mathcal{I}$ and all $\{x\}$ with $x \in S\setminus \bigcup \mathcal{I}$. The order on $S$ induces an order on the quotient space, because all classes are order-convex (we identify all intervals in $\mathcal{I}$ to a new point) (i.e. define $[x] \le [y]$ iff $x \le y$ and check this is well-defined). Then take $p,q$ two new points (not in $S$ or the quotient) and extend this order by $p < x < q$ for all $x$ in the quotient (adding a minimum and a maximum). This new ordered set is our $S’$. $S’$ is order complete if $S$ was, so if complete, it will be compact (which in ordered spaces is equivalent to every subset having a minimum, hence the need for the min and max).

Comment: Thanks so much. I believe the main idea I was missing is that they *had* to be disjoint. Much easier to see now.

Comment: @GoodMorningCaptain Your welcome. I used this fact in my PhD-thesis so I’m very familiar with it. Start with a non-separable ccc linear space. Identify neighbours (points $x < y$ with no point in between) and take the completion (still non-separable and ccc by standard facts). Now the space is connected ordered. Then do this construction as I described and we get a connected and compact ccc non-separable linearly ordered topological space.

Comment: And for linearly ordered spaces we have that ccc implies hereditarily ccc and hereditarily Lindelöf. And combining with the compactness we get perfectly normal and first countable too. A very nice L-space.